# Logback for webapp created inside tomcat/bin

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, log4j, logback

I have created webapp and for logging I have decided to use logback. When I run the tomcat server, the log folder/file is getting created inside the bin folder of the tomcat. But I want the log to go into the tomcats log folder. Below the contents of my logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{5} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${catalina.base}/logs/myLogFile.log</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${catalina.base}/logs/myLogFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <MaxFileSize>2MB</MaxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.test.myapp" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </logger>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Comment: I'm guessing you're not able to define `catalina.base` and therefore this configuration results in your log going to a `catalina.base_IS_UNDEFINED` folder.